# how to find in between Ou=9999998 Only number

Tags: asp-classic

[image]

How to find in between `Ou=9999998` Only number

For example
suppose this is my string `cn=54445sddsfsd`, `ou=99988855`, `o=fgfgfdg`, `u=dfddfgfgg`. `subject=5454gffdgfg454hg` I want to declare only `ou=99988855`

Comment: No idea what you want

Comment: supose this is my string cn=54445sddsfsd,ou=99988855,o=fgfgfdg,u=dfddfgfgg.subject=5454gffdgfg454hg  i want to declare only   ou=99988855

Comment: Perhaps you should reword your question so that we can more easily understand.  Give examples and try reading the [help].

Answer (score 0):

```
<%
  dim str,strArray,ouStr
  str = "cn=54445sddsfsd,ou=99988855,o=fgfgfdg,u=dfddfgfgg.subject=5454gffdgfg454hg"
  strArray = split(str,",")
  for i=0 to ubound(strArray)
    if instr(strArray(i),"ou")>0 then
      ouStr = strArray(i)
    end if
  next
response.Write ouStr
%>
```

Comment: document.login_Mktg.hidsubjectdn1.value=obj.SignSubjName my string inside this document how to declare

Comment: What? If that is your string then just use it in the above code

Comment: please convert to asp.net c#

Comment: How about you do that?